# navigation bar generated using data base is not working properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, tile

i generated navigation bar using data base.1st time the navigation bar is working fine.but when click on sub menu and then 2nd time click on main menu the sub menu are  not displays. don't know is it toggling or sub menus are not there.i pass sub menu and main menus by session variables.

i use tile and spring mvc.

menujsp:

```
    <%@page import="net.opticare.service.LoginServiceImpl"%>
    <%@page import="net.opticare.service.LoginService"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ page import="net.opticare.service.LoginService"%>
    <%@ page import="net.opticare.service.LoginServiceImpl"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@ page import="net.opticare.form.Subtab"%>
    <%@ page import="net.opticare.form.Maintab"%>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


     <% 

    LoginService loginService=new LoginServiceImpl();
    int usertype=(Integer)session.getAttribute("usertype");
    List<Maintab> MaintabsList=(List<Maintab>)session.getAttribute("MaintabsList");
    List<Subtab> SubtabsList=(List<Subtab>)session.getAttribute("SubtabsList");
    try{

        request.setAttribute("MaintabsList", MaintabsList);
        request.setAttribute("SubtabsList", SubtabsList);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    %>
        <nav id="bb" class="navbar navbar-default">

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                            class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                            class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="Loginsucess">home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                    id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <c:if test="${not empty SubtabsList}">
                            <c:forEach var="maintab" items="${MaintabsList}">
                                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">${maintab.description}
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <c:forEach var="subtab" items="${SubtabsList}">
                                            <c:if test="${subtab.maintab.maiTabId == maintab.maiTabId}">
                                                <li><a href="${subtab.ref}">${subtab.description}</a></li>
                                            </c:if>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:if>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

login controller  :

```
if(userExists!=0){
            /*model.addAttribute("Maintabs",new Maintab());
             model.addAttribute("MaintabsList",loginService.listMaintabs(userExists));
             model.addAttribute("Subtabs",new Subtab());
             model.addAttribute("SubtabsList",loginService.listSubtab(userExists));
            */ 
            HttpSession session1 = request.getSession(); 
             session1.setAttribute("usertype", userExists);
             session1.setAttribute("MaintabsList", loginService.listMaintabs(userExists));
             session1.setAttribute("SubtabsList", loginService.listSubtab(userExists));

            System.out.println("session attri  :"+session1.getAttribute("MaintabsList"));
             return "Loginsucess";
```

tiles xml :

```
<tiles-definitions>  

    <definition name="base.definition"  
        template="/WEB-INF/jsp/main.jsp">  
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />  
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />  
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />  
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />  
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />  
    </definition>  

    <definition name="loginform" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/loginform.jsp"/>

    <definition name="userRedirect" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title"  value="User Management" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/UserManagement.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="usertype" extends="base.definition">     
        <put-attribute name="title"  value="User Type Management" />         
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/UserTypeManagement.jsp" />            
    </definition>
        <definition name="AddUpdateCustomer" extends="base.definition">     
        <put-attribute name="title"  value="Customer Management" />         
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/CustomerManagement.jsp" />            
    </definition>


    <definition name="Loginsucess" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title"  value="Wel Come To Opticare Vision House"/>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/Home.jsp" />          
    </definition> 

</tiles-definitions>
```

customermanagement jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
legend a {
    color: inherit;
}

legend.legendStyle {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

fieldset.fsStyle {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

legend.legendStyle {
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #888888;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
}

legend {
    width: auto;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}

.top-buffer {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.margin {
    /*  margin-left:30px;
  margin-right:10px; */
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadDataToThegrid() {

        // get the form values

        //var name = $('#name').val();

        //var education = $('#education').val();

        $.ajax({

            type : "POST",

            url : "ListCustomer",

            // data: "name=" + name + "&education=" + education,
            data : {},
            success : function(response) {

                // we have the response

                alert(response);

            },

            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert('Error: ' +xhr.responseText);
                alert('Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

            }

        });

    }
    function loaddata() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ListCustomer',
            error : function(xhr, statusText, err) {
                alert("error" + xhr.status);
            },

            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            type : 'GET'
        });
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" >

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row top-buffer">
                    <fieldset class="fsStyle">
                        <div class="col-md-8">

                            <div class="row top-buffer">
                                <div class="col-md-4 margin">
                                    <input type="text" value="First Name" id="txtfname" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 margin">
                                    <input type="text" value="Contact No" id="txtContactNo" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row top-buffer ">
                                <div class="col-md-8 margin">
                                    <input type="text" value="Last Name" id="txtLname" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row top-buffer">
                                <div class="col-md-8 margin">
                                    <input type="text" value="Address" id="txtAddress" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row top-buffer">
                                <div class="col-md-2 margin">
                                    <input type="button" value="    Save   " id="btnSave" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 margin">
                                    <input type="button" value="View History" id="btnHistory" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 margin">
                                    <input type="button" value="Prescription" id="btnPrescription" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 margin">
                                    <input type="button" value="    Back    " id="btnBack" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <img
                                src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/img/rsz_indexpage_image.jpg"
                                height="150" width="150" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="row top-buffer">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="container" style="overflow: auto;">
                            <table id="tblcustoDetails" class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Customer ID</th>
                                        <th>First Name</th>
                                        <th>Last Name</th>
                                        <th>Address</th>
                                        <th>Tel No</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i imparted bootstrap.min.css,jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js  in both menu jsp and customermanagment jsp. when comment on custometmangement jsp import it's working fine.

change CustomerManagement.jsp  as below  :

```
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
```